# Error while training an object detector with my own dataset using Tensorflow's Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-slim

I'm working on training an object detector with tensor flow's object detector API. I'm following [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) to train an object detector with my own dataset. Everything seems to be fine until i started the training process (locally):

```
python /Users/vinayakpahalwan/models/research/object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=/Users/vinayakpahalwan/Desktop/ObjectDetection/training/ --pipeline_config_path=/Users/vinayakpahalwan/Desktop/ObjectDetection/training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

I'm getting the following **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/Users/vinayakpahalwan/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import matcher_builder
  File "/Users/vinayakpahalwan/models/research/object_detection/builders/matcher_builder.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.matchers import bipartite_matcher
  File "/Users/vinayakpahalwan/models/research/object_detection/matchers/bipartite_matcher.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.image.python.ops import image_ops
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.image'
```

I'm kinda stuck here as of now, any workaround for that?

I guess i have installed the object detection API correctly as per [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) :

```
Vinayaks-MacBook-Air:object_detection vinayakpahalwan$ python builders/model_builder_test.py
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 0.070s

OK
```

Comment: Can u try going to the file _bipartite_matcher.py_ in line 20 then changing `from tensorflow.contrib.image.python.ops import image_ops` to `from tensorflow.python.ops import image_ops` and let me know if it works

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: @eshirima Not getting the same error instead I'm getting this `File "/Users/vinayakpahalwan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 472, in Merge
    text.split('\n'),
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @eshirima tensorflow (0.12.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that it cannot locate the file *tensorflow/contrib/image*.

Since you are using Tensorflow version 0.12.1, looking inside [*tensorflow/contrib*](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib), the folder *image* does not exist yet. This is introduced from version 1.0 as seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib).

Your workaround at this point is updating TS.